# SageMaker Studio domain creation fails due to KMS permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services

## Question

Please help understand the cause and solution for the problem.

## Problem

SageMaker Studio domain creation fails due to KMS permissions. The IAM Role specified to the SageMaker arn:aws:iam::316725000538:role/SageMaker has the permissions for KMS required as specified in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/api-permissions-reference.html.

> Domain creation failed
> Unable to create Amazon EFS for domain 'd-1dq5c9rpkswy' because you don't have permissions to use the KMS key 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:316725000538:key/1e2dbf9d-daa0-408d-a290-1633b615c54f'. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/api-permissions-reference.html for required permissions for CreateDomain action.

[image] tells the IAM permissions

## IAM Permission for CreateDomain action

- [Amazon SageMaker API Permissions: Actions, Permissions, and Resources Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/api-permissions-reference.html)

[image]

The IAM permission required for the CreateDomain action have been attached to the IAM role.

[image]

Comment: To diagnose first give that role admin permissions, if it then works it's an IAM issue, if not it's something else. The something else could be the KMS key policy.